# Expressjs doesn't load static files

Tags: node.js, express

I have two different ExpressJS apps running on same server (via nginx proxy). They both use the same version of express (4.18.2) and both have the same file structure, where "app.js" is in the top level app directory, and so is the "public" directory.

The app.js for both contains the following:

```
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
...
// Routes
app.use('/', require(path.join(__dirname, '/routes/index')));
app.use('/users', require(path.join(__dirname, '/routes/users')));
```

Each app's pages include a file header.ejs that contains the navbar and a  section containing references to static files stored in "public/css" and "public/js" directories:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/css/main.css' />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/jquery.cookieBar.css">
... Navbar stuff...
<script src="/js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" </script>
<script src="/js/jquery.cookieBar.min.js" </script>
```

On one app, everything works as expected, but on the other, NO local files are found. It's mindboggling to me, because I have used this same structure for a dozen different apps, and with no problems. I've been struggling with this for hours, and nothing is working.

Also: both work as expected on when running locally (on Mac mini)

Edit:

I've also tried removing preceding slashes on /css and /js, to no avail.

I've also tried adding the following lines below the routes section in app.js:

```
app.use("/css", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public", "css")));
app.use("/js", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public", "js")));
```

Any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, there was a line in the nginx virtual host file for the non-working site that was causing the error:

`try_files $uri $uri/ =404;`